# Imagem dentro de um ScrollView fica em branco em um aparelho mas aparece normalmente em outro

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tenho um AlertDialog cujo conteúdo é um ScrollView com uma imagem e um botão dentro. O ScrollView funciona funciona (consigo "rolar" a barrinha), mas a imagem não aparece (fica em branco), apesar de que o botão aparece (ao rolar até o final). Já no celular de um amigo meu, a imagem aparece. Creio que a única diferença do celular dele para o meu seja a versão do Android: o dele é 6.0 e o meu 4 alguma coisa. Segue o código XML do layout que inflo no AlertDialog:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imagem_teste" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/viewfinder_laser"
    android:text="Entendi"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse" />


</LinearLayout>
```

E o código do botão que cria e mostra o diálogo:

```
btnSobre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alerta, null);

                view.findViewById(R.id.bt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        alerta.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelaInicial.this);
                builder.setTitle("Sobre...");
                builder.setView(view);
                alerta = builder.create();
                alerta.show();

            }
        }
);
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o por quê da imagem não aparecer?

Comment: Já testou no emulador? Dá pra você testar em versões diferentes do Android e ver se o problema é a versão mesmo.

Comment: Em que pasta está a imagem? Que o tipo de drawable é(png, jpg, xml/svg, outro)?

Comment: C:\Users\usuario\AndroidStudioProjects\MeuApp\app\src\main\res\drawable. É jpg.

Comment: Nao Pablo, não testei, mas é uma boa dica. No entanto quando abro o emulador meu pc fica meio lento, principalmente se eu tiver mais coisa aberta. Só o android studio roda bem de boas, por isso não uso o emulador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui arrumar. Configurei como falso a aceleração de hardware no Manifest.
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Answer (score 0):

Tenta recolocar a imagem por linha de programação

```
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelaInicial.this);
            builder.setTitle("Sobre...");
            builder.setView(view);  //a proxima linha seta a imagem na view
            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID_IMAGEVIEW)).setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();
```

Comment: Não funcionou Caio. Sinceramente, não sei mais o que fazer. No celular do meu amigo fica perfeito e no meu fica em branco, embora apareça a rolagem e o botao no final do scroll view.